# Using OpenCV to Solve for Transform between non planar object Points and image points

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision, augmented-reality

**QUESTION REPOSTED TO ADD CLARITY**

I am working with OpenCV to try to calibrate a Laser Scanner.

I have a set of 2d points captured by the scanner. For the sake of the example, let's let these points be represented as follows:

```
IMAGE POINTS
{(0.08017784, -0.08993121, 0)}
{(-0.1127666, -0.08712908, 0)}
{(-0.1117229, 0.1782855, 0)}
{(0.09053531, 0.198439, 0)}
```

I know that these points correspond to the following real world points:

```
OBJECT POINTS
{(0, 0, 0)}
{(190, 0, 0)}
{(190, 260, 0)}
{(0, 260, 122)}
```

I have been using OpenCV To solve for a rotation and translation matrix that will allow me to give a world point (100, 200, 20, for example) and get back the 2d point in the captured coordinate system.

My results thus far have shown that if the object points are co-planar then OpenCV finds the rotation/translation results almost perfectly.

However, in problems like the example I gave above where not all the points lie on the same plane, I am getting wildly wrong answers.

I know that this is possible (not necessarily with openCV) because I have another commercial software that can do this. For reference, the solution to the above problem is the matrix:

```
SOLUTION
[-0.99668, 0.03056, 0.07543]
[ 0.05860, 0.91263, 0.40454]
[-0.05647, 0.40762,-0.91140]
[79.34385, -89.63855,-982.25938]
```

I am using a root mean square error to determine validity of results. The root mean square error for the solution I provided is 1.61560. While the result from OpenCV is over 1000.

**THE QUESTION:**

Using the given IMAGE POINTS and OBJECT POINTS how can one use OpenCV (or other methods) to arrive at the SOLUTION.

**What I have already tried:**

I have tried the basic SolvePNP from OpenCV like so:

```
Cv2.SolvePnP(objectPoints, imagePoints, camMatrix, dist, out double[] rvec, out double[] tvec, false, SolvePnPFlags.Iterative);
```

[Documentation on SolvePNP Here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga549c2075fac14829ff4a58bc931c033d)

As stated above, this solution works if my object points are all planar. But with points on other planes the solution breaks down and is very wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SolvePnP works with any 3d points, are you sure that you have the same coord system for the image and object points? And that you have the correct corresponances

Comment: @MartinBeckett I am certain, yes. I use the exact same solution on scenarios where the objects points are planar with no problems. As soon as the object points are not planar there are issues.

Comment: SolvePnP can give flipped solutions. Check the determinant() of the rotation matrix, you can use this to flip the axis correctly.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Upon taking the determinant I get a double value back. what should I be looking for in this double value and what should I flip to make the solution correct

Comment: @MartinBeckett So i experimented a bit and I do see that I am getting some incorrect signs on my rotation matricies (but only sometimes). And the determinant of a good solution and a bad are both 1 (or nearly 1 e.g. 0.99999997)

Comment: Did you try `solvePnPRansac`?

Comment: I have tried ransac, but I get some exceptions that I can't clear. I don't think ransac, is the right solution because in many cases I will only have 4 data points and don't have any outliers.

Comment: What happens if you scale your 3d object points first to be mostly between -1 and 1? i.e. try dividing by something like 400 before solving? You can then factor this value back into the camera matrix.

Also, the gotcha @MartinBeckett alluded in the documentation:

`With SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE method and useExtrinsicGuess=true, the minimum number of points is 3 (3 points are sufficient to compute a pose but there are up to 4 solutions). The initial solution should be close to the global solution to converge.`

Comment: Is initial guess possible? SolvePNP tends to return better result if an initial guess is provided. It doesnt have to be really close to the answer, just close enough to prevent it from diverging to spurious answers. It can be as simple as an average of all possible formation of the object.

Comment: I think we might need the original image coordinates and image size for your scanner to recover the camera matrix (or the camera matrix itself).  Can't test the example without a camera matrix.

Anyways, if you ignore the camera parameters, and are only interested in mapping back and forth between the two, the least squares solution to this is PsuedoInverse(obj_points) * img_points.  You can then recover an image point by multiplying a new object point by that matrix. (new_obj * Pinv(obj) * img)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Sorry forgot to follow up on this)

Calculate the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) of the rotation matrix. It should be =1 for a 'correct' answer and -1 for the flipped one. Then simply multiply the rotation by a [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) matrix where the last term is the determinant. this does nothing if the det() =1 but flips it back to the correct answer if the det() is = -1

You might find the code/discussion on [POSE ESTIMATION FOR PLANAR TARGET](https://nghiaho.com/?page_id=576) useful

Comment: I've accepted this answer. It solves the issue of reverse rotations, but it doesn't solve the issue of plain incorrect solutions occasionally. For some reason it chooses to converge on a rmse of ~10 occasionally when the competing software converges at 1.

Comment: @Kikootwo Did you manage to find a solution to that?